# How to match two voice files and return whether they are the same words?

Tags: ios, artificial-intelligence, pattern-matching, voice-recognition, pattern-recognition

I record my voice with words "Hello World" and save it as file-1.

Then record the voice of another guy with "Hello World" and save it as file-2.

Is there any way to match these two files ?

I mean ,if the two files have the same words recorded, they should be equal.

Please tell me some open source project or papers to read.

Comment: Finding out the answer to this question yourself is way easier than understanding the papers that will help you solve the problem. Consider it as an easy exercise. But: Do you simply need a solution that works or are you interested in how it is done?

Comment: @ziggystar Well, i need to know how to make it done first....but additionally i really like to know how it works.

Comment: You could try some speaker independent voice recognition package that doesn't require a predetermined vocabulary to convert the wav into a text. But this will most probably not work very well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to play around [Dynamic Time Warping algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_time_warping)

Here is example of using DTW algorithm in appliance to speech recognition http://www.cnel.ufl.edu/~kkale/6825Project.html